# Facebook like button & events

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

Some questions for you fb-experts :)

If i want to "like" a companys facebook page, from a completly different url (lets say their homepage for example). Is all i need to do add a like button with the `href` set to the facebook page?

I know that theres a javascript event for when someone press a like button. Is there any way to check if the user already likes the page when he enters the site with the button? Or is this only possible server-side?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you even tried what's in the documentation? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to check if the user already likes the page when he
>   enters the site with the button?

yes, but the user will need to authorize your app to be able to query the user's likes

> Or is this only possible server-side?

Nope, it can be done server-side or client-side.

Comment: But without an app, its serverside only?

Comment: You need an app (and app id) even server-side to check if the user has liked a page